# Python selenium ошибка

Tags: python, selenium

Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Ошибка:

```
C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/learn_python/sel.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/learn_python/sel.py", line 2, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x004FE1F0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 173, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 145, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

В чем дело?

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")` - попробуйте так, указав свой путь к `chromedriver.exe`

Comment: Прошу прощения, всё сработало. Большое спасибо!